# Way to Secure token generated by OAuth server

Tags: jwt, token, access-token, keycloak

I am exploring OAuth implementation using keycloak. Whenever we authenticate on client, keycloak returns JWT token to the client application. This token has to be persisted in client end for further communication. Chance of token hijack is high in this scenario.

Can anyone suggest better option to securely transfer the token between client and server?

Comment: are you worried about persistence, or transfer, or both?

Comment: Any alternate way to return reference to access token generated from auth server...